# What can I learn from this man's uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, uniform, jews, poland, poland-lithuania

This is my Polish Great Grandfather - I'm trying to create his story by looking at his uniform. Imperial Russian Uniform? Lithuanian cross? Help!
[image: Szmul Ajzyk "Jacques" Geller 1889 - 1942]
Photo taken in Saint Petersburg, Russia
He was born in Warsaw, murdered in Auschwitz.
Who can help me understand his life?
Thanks,